# Aprrove and transfer a ERC20 token to a contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I need to use a contract to trigger a function and transfer the token of the msg.sender to (this) contract. I can do it with the "approve" function in the Token contract, but I can't do it with this contract it self.

Any idea?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract ERC20 {

    address public tokenAddr = (my token address);
    ERC20 public token;

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns(bool);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
}

contract SAY is ERC20 {

    string word = 'Something';

    function SAYSOMETHING() public returns(string)  {

        token.approve(msg.sender, 500);
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender,this, 500);
        return word;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to have the contract just take your tokens without you `approve`ing it first? That, of course, can't be done. Could you explain the scenario better?

Comment: I'm trying to make a function "payable" with tokens.

Comment: For an account (including a contract) to call `transferFrom`, the owner of the tokens must first call `approve`. So the caller of `SAYSOMETHING` must first call `tokenAddr.approve(SAY, tokenAmount)`.

Comment: I can do that in the same function?

Comment: No, the _caller_ needs to call `approve`. The contract can't just give itself permission to take somebody's tokens. :-)

Comment: `function SAYSOMETHING() public returns(string)  {
      
      token.approve(this, 200);
      token.transferFrom(msg.sender, this, 200);` likes this?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. Do you not understand what "caller" means?

Comment: I was just finding a way to that with just one transaction

Comment: You can't do it with one transaction with a standard ERC-20 token.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by smarx, the user needs to call the approve function outside of the contract, then the contract will be able to transfer tokens on the behalf of the user.

You could allow this with a slight change/addition to the ERC20 standard implementation. If the token you want to use is not yet defined, I would explore this option as well.